# How can my java program launch another java program in the console window?

Tags: java, cmd, runtime.exec

I have a Java program that runs in the command line window. In that program I would like to have it launch a different Java application but in the same console window. Is this at all possible? I've tried using:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] params = {"/c", "java", "-jar", "program.jar"};
runtime.exec("cmd", params);
```

And I've tried:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] params = {"-jar", "program.jar"};
runtime.exec("java", params");
```

I've tried both but neither actually did anything. Can I do this using just Java?

Comment: To be in the "same console" you need to capture and handle the Input and Error streams, and need to send data to the OutputStream. I don't see you doing that in your code snippet above. Better still, don't post code snippets. Post a small self-contained runnable program that demonstrates your problem, a [mcve].

Comment: It also depends on what program jar application does, can you give details on that ???

Comment: Okay. How would I capture the process's error and input streams?

Comment: By reading one of the *thousands* of tutorials and similar questions out there.

Comment: S u c h   a s . . ?

Comment: Start [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html). It's a little dated -- you should use ProcessBuilder, not `runtime.exec()`, but it will give you some solid foundation.

Comment: Answer accepted, that is if it were an answer, not a comment.